# Finding the $n^{th}$ derivative of $x^r$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, factorial

I'm looking for a **non-piecewise** function -- $g(n,x)$ -- that satisfies this equation:

> $g(n,x)=\large\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}x^{r}$
>
> Where $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ and is the $n^{th}$ derivitive of $f(x)$

I think I've found $g(n,x)$, but I'm not sure. This is what I've come up with

$\large\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}x^{r} =\large\large\frac{x^{r-n}r!}{(r-n)!}$

Below is my reasoning

---

The power rule for derivatives, states that

$\frac{d^{}}{dx^{}}x^{r}=r(x^{r-1})$

A natural consequence is that

$\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}x^{r}=r(r-1)(x^{r-2})$

and...

$\frac{d^{3}}{dx^{3}}x^{r}=r(r-1)(r-2)(x^{r-3})$

Following this pattern gets you my original equation

---

Can anyone verify weather or not this is correct or not? If so, would this work for all values of $r$ and $n$, including when $n < 0$ (the $n^{th}$ integral)? I don't know if there is a way to use negative factorials, but if there is, would this still hold true?

Also, I'm wondering if there a more generalized solution to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can you have $n \lt 0$? What does $\frac{d^{n}y}{dx^{n}}$ mean then?

Comment: I was thinking integrals @peter.petrov

Comment: What is a non-piecewise function?

Comment: Something that's not [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise)

Comment: I think you mean $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^r$, not $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}x^r$

Comment: you're right @MPW. I'll edit it now

Comment: If you are thinking of $D^n$ as the $n$-fold differential operator, and using $D^{-n}$ as an $n$-fold antiderivative, then you have to be careful. The $n$-fold antiderivative is only determined up to an additive polynomial of degreen $n-1$. That's because $D^n\{f\} = D^n\{f + P_{n-1}\}$, where $P_k$ is any polynomial of degree at most $k$; that follows from the fact that when you take a single antiderivative, you have an arbitrary constant to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \frac{{\rm d}^n}{{\rm d}x^n} x^r = \frac{r!}{(r-n)!} x^{r-n} $$

You are correct

$$ = r (r-1) (r-2) \ldots (r-n+1) \,x^{r-n} $$

Run a few test cases through Wolfram Alpha and you can confirm this yourself.

Comment: Classic example of "Proof by Wolfram Alpha". =)

Comment: Heh. Not proof, but confirmation.